# Clipboard not working on geany via macports on mavericks

Tags: macports, geany

I installed macports on mavericks, changed the macports flags to

```
+no_x11
-x11
+quartz
```

Then proceeded to install geany.
Now the clipboard does not work for geany at all. Not outside of geany nor inside it. The clipboard exchange does work on other X11 apps, like xterm.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, by uninstalling everything and removing the restrictions on the variants I got the clipboard to work. Why would the geany team suggest you do this anyways? (it did work well on Lion, though)

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how did you do the things you mentioned? Is there a blog or something documented about this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike seeing unanswered answers, so I will try to answer. My answer is shallow in my opinion, but I hope it helps.

Shallow answer:

There is some odd bug associated with the macports and clipboard.

References:

http://bugs.gramps-project.org/view.php?id=3089

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/33885

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/17434

http://tinos-diary.blogspot.com/2007/06/mac-port-clipboard-work-completed.html

I hope you are satisfied with that answer. Unfortunately, I do not know macports well enough to explain why the clipboard and macports have conflicts. All that I know is that there is some bug.